# Learn threshold for multi-label classification

Tags: neural-networks, threshold, multilabel

I have a multi-label problem which I'm tackling with a NN. To get the multi-label scores, I use a tanh on the last layers (as suggested in the literature), and then selecting the ones corresponding to a classified label according to a threshold (which, again, is often suggested to be put at 0.5). For example (pseudocode of what's happening in the network):

```
threshold = 0.5
last_hidden = [1,0.995,0.39,-0.283,-1.033]
multi_label_scores = tanh(last_hidden)  # [ 0.7615942 ,  0.7594864 ,  0.3713602 , -0.27567932, -0.77510875]
labels = [1 for s in multi_label_scores if s >= threshold] # [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

My question is: apart from putting the threshold to 0.5, or maybe finding a better value during the parameter tuning, is there a way to learn such threshold, for example using specific max-margin loss functions (or similar)?

---- EDIT ----
The suggested threshold would be actually 0 for a tanh, not 0.5 (which would be used for a sigmoid). Anyway, it's just a translation. The problem is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Threshold for your output neuron is also a *hyper-parameter* and can be tuned just like others. The $0.5$ suggestion is probably for sigmoid function, because it is symmetric around 0 and hits $0.5$ at $0$. Similarly for tanh ([check](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hyperbolic_function) its symmetry), the so-called suggested is probably $0$, not $0.5$. But this is like saying your suggested neural network size is 2 layers etc. You should also tune your threshold. Several statistics such as ROC curve, Precision/Recall curves are obtained the measure the performance while changing this threshold, and they're used to understand the behavior of the system. By the way, a more commonly suggested option for *sigmoid*, for instance, is to use your class priors.

Comment: Yep, the 0.5 was a legacy of something written in an old document. Of course for tanh that would be 0. But, apart from tuning it, I was wondering whether the computation of the threshold could be integrated in the cost function somehow (like minimising de distance from an hyperplane). Moreover, when you refer to priors, you mean using priors of single classes to calculate separate thresholds for each class?

Comment: e.g. for sigmoid $\theta=p(C_0)$ may be another suggestion for setting the threshold. This value can be 1-1 mapped to tanh. But, I'm not saying this is the best way. If say, you have a logistic regression, i.e. a NN with one neuron, trying to find the best (e.g. best-margin) hyperplane corresponds to SVMs. But, I don't think there exists an equivalent procedure for general NNs.

Comment: @McKracken does this answer your question? I see that it's been a while.